# Eslint plugin import rule to detect missing properties in module.exports

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-plugin-import

I have the following files:

```js
// abc.js
module.exports = {
  def: 7,
  ghi: 8,
}

// export const def = 7
// export const ghi = 8
```

and

```js
// importing.js
import { xyz } from './abc.js'
```

My IDE (Webstorm) correctly warns that xyz is not on the module.exports through own code analysis.
But eslint with the eslint-plugin-import does not report an error. It does though if I change abc.js to use named es6 exports (as in the commented code)

Which rule do I have to add to make it work?
Tried a few combinations but didn't find the appropiate one.
My current rules field in my eslintrc is

```js
{
  'import/no-unresolved': [2, {commonjs: true, amd: true}],
  'import/named': 2,
  'import/no-named-as-default': 2,
  'import/no-named-default': 2,
}
```